# Releasing connections in a connection pool.

Tags: c#, sql, active-directory, ado.net

So I inherited a software program in the form of a COM DLL. (No Source Code, just the setup.exe)

The DLL connects to Active Directory via ADO.NET, and passes a string back via a method to authenticate a user. (This takes a second at most)

The problem is, for each user authenticated, it opens a connection in the connection pool, but seemingly does not close it. Thus after 100 tries I get the error:

**"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."**

My Question is: How do I go about resetting the connection pool when it reaches 100? 
Is there maybe a registry setting where I can change the Max number of connections? 
Maybe write a script that runs every hour or so and clear the pool?
Ideally having the source code would be nice, to fix the connection string with the correct parameters, but that's not available here.

Any suggestions.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you close the connection after you are done using it. You can explicitly call the close method

```
//do something with the conn
conn.Close();
```

**Or**

use the [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block which will take care of closing the connection once the code inside the using block is executed

```
using(var conn=new SqlConnection("YourConnectionStringHere"))
{
  conn.Open();
  // do something
}
```

`using` statement will take care of disposing the connection as well.

Comment: Having same issue and I see how I opened connections and didn't close them because I stopped my application before it could call Close() but now every time I run it, it won't let me make a connection. How can I close them after the fact or clear the pool? Where is this being stored?